# Hide table row if no data

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress to create new content types. In my template, I have styled the text to be in a table layout like so:

```
<table class="members">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <h3>Basic Information</h3>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p><strong>Parent Organization:</strong> <?php the_field('parent_organization'); ?></p>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, if a member of the website has not put in their Parent Organization, I want to hide that entire row. I've looked at several other examples of how to do this in jQuery, but no answer is working. Since I'm using a child theme, I added a new functions.php AND my own child-theme-custom.js to my child theme folder.

Examples of three different attempts that did not work:

```
$('.members tr').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('td:eq(1):empty').length > 0;
}).hide(); 

$('.members td').find('td:eq(1):empty').parent().hide();

$('.members > tbody  > tr').has('td:empty').hide()
```

Comment: you can use the :empty css selector to display:hide; whatever you want ...

Comment: Quite likely your JS is runs before the DOM is ready .... to confirm, right before the code above, add this line: `alert( $('.members').length )`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the td is not empty because you are showing this whether or not the 'parent_organization' is present:

```
<p><strong>Parent Organization:</strong></p>
```

Thus the cell is not empty. Check out this fiddle for some fuel for your brain: http://jsfiddle.net/mx07d7fz/

Plus it is a good idea to make sure your DOM is ready as stated in the comment by user3558931.